# How to breakdown denormalized table(M:M) to data model (from same table)?

Tags: database, data-modeling, data-warehouse, datamodel, azure-synapse

I'd like to ask question about how to model data from the same table

**Source Table : Customer**

```
Fields : cust_id , Firstname , LastName , Address No , Street , Province , PostalCode
```

**TO BE MODEL**

TABLE : Customer

```
Fields : cust_id , Firstname , LastName
```

TABLE : House

```
Fields : House_id, Address No , Street , Province , PostalCode
```

TABLE : CUST_HOUSE_RELATION

```
FIELD : CUST_ID,HOUSE_ID,RELATE_TYPE
```

**INFO**

- 1 Customer M Houses(address) and 1 House(address) M Customers
- Create CUST_HOUSE_RELATION to solve M:M relationship
- There is no Table Address (separated)

**Problem**

- I cannot define HouseID because there is no addressid from Source (Table customer contains customer info and address info (with no key of address info). Please suggest.

Comment: Is this a once off data migration exercise? You need to generate the key. Insert the house record, capture the id and use it when inserting the CUST_HOUSE_RELATION record.  The final model doesn't actually fit the input data.

Comment: May I ask, If I generate House Id, how can I join HouseId and cust_id ? I mean I don't know which fields I can use to join between HouseId and Cust Id

Comment: Is this a once off data migration exercise?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach but whether this is suitable depends on what you are doing.

1. Add `cust_id` column field to `house`
2. Load `customer` and `house` from source table, ensuring you populate `house.cust_id`
3. I assume `house.house_id` will autogenerate, but you don't provide enough info to tell
4. Load `cust_hous_relation` from `house` (it has both keys in it)
5. Drop `cust_id` from `house`

You haven't provided enough info to give a proper solution.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I am implementing data warehouse (to keep relation and history data) prepare for datamart. I mean data will be loaded into  data model every day automatically.

Comment: A datawarehouse load usually contains a staging layer. This is where you can apply the logic I have described above